# remove closure slash '/' from img tag of XHTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend, xhtml

I have a string `txt1` that stores an image. Its value is in XHTML, i.e. the element is closed: `<img src="happy.gif" alt="Happy face" />`. But I need to remove that closure slash, so it can be `<img src="happy.gif" alt="Happy face">` as in HTML5.

Is there a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const txt1 = '<img src="happy.gif" alt="Happy face" />'.replace('/>', '>');
console.log(txt1)
```